# Is it possible to find the position of spherical ball only using gyroscope raw data?

Tags: rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity, gyroscopes

Assuming the spherical ball undergoes pure rolling and errors from gyroscope can neglected. Can I use angular velocity from gyroscope to find the position by computing rotations times its radius?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning

Answer (score 0):

If your sphere is rolling in a straight line on a hard level surface, then there is no torque which would cause a precession.  Then s = Rωt.